# Putting the vertices of a rectangle in order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, math, geometry

I'm trying to write a function in python(2.7).
This function will take a list of 8 values which represents the coordinates of vertices.
( Form of the input is [Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy] )
The function will determine whether these vertices are given in order to form a valid rectangle.

If not, it will put them in order and return a sorted list of these vertices.
The starting point or the direction(whether it is clockwise or anti-clockwise) is not important.

Let me illusrate what I want:
If the given input forms the 2nd or 3rd shape in the link below; the function will convert it to the first one.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsRqr.png

### Which algorithm can I use to do this?

I have used the way Alexey suggested and wrote my code.
It can take some optimizations but it is not neccessary for me atm.

```
def crossProduct(vector1,vector2) :
    a,b,c = vector1
    d,e,f = vector2
    vector3 = (b*f-c*e , -a*f+c*d , a*e-b*d)
    return vector3

def fixRect(rectList) :
    Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy = rectList[:]
    v12 = (Bx-Ax,By-Ay,0)
    v13 = (Cx-Ax,Cy-Ay,0)
    v14 = (Dx-Ax,Dy-Ay,0)
    z1 = crossProduct(v13,v12)[2]
    z2 = crossProduct(v13,v14)[2]
    if z1*z2 < 0 : # if two z values have different sign, they are in order
        return [Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy]
    # else swap 2 and 3
    Ax,Ay,Cx,Cy,Bx,By,Dx,Dy = rectList[:]
    # repeat
    v12 = (Bx-Ax,By-Ay,0)
    v13 = (Cx-Ax,Cy-Ay,0)
    v14 = (Dx-Ax,Dy-Ay,0)
    z1 = crossProduct(v13,v12)[2]
    z2 = crossProduct(v13,v14)[2]
    if z1*z2 < 0 : # if two z values have different sign, they are in order
        return [Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy]
    # else swap 3 and 4
    Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Dx,Dy,Cx,Cy = rectList[:]
    # repeat
    v12 = (Bx-Ax,By-Ay,0)
    v13 = (Cx-Ax,Cy-Ay,0)
    v14 = (Dx-Ax,Dy-Ay,0)
    z1 = crossProduct(v13,v12)[2]
    z2 = crossProduct(v13,v14)[2]
    if z1*z2 < 0 : # if two z values have different sign, they are in order
        return [Ax,Ay,Bx,By,Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy]
    else: raise Exception("Couldn't fix the rectangle")
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Why not post some code?

Comment: I can determine whether they are in order or not, by comparing the slopes of counter sides, but I can't put them in order if they are random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a vector from point 1 to point 2.

Make a vector from point 1 to point 3.

Make a vector from point 1 to point 4.

Calculate the z component of the cross product of the vectors 1->3 and 1->2.

Calculate the z component of the cross product of the vectors 1->3 and 1->4.

If those two z's have different signs (one is negative and the other is positive), you have your points in order.

If they aren't in order, repeat all of the above, first swapping points 3 and 2. And if that's not sufficient, then swap points 3 and 4 in the original list/array of points.

Comment: +1 - nice use of x-product.  The OP doesn't say whether the "correct" order requires clockwise or counterclockwise order when looking down the plane's unit vector.  I would want them to follow a counterclockwise, right hand rule ordering.

Comment: @duffymo Once you've got the points in one of two orders, you can reverse it if necessary (based on the sign of one of those z's).

Comment: @duffymo: “The starting point or the direction is not important.” Suggests to me that either order will work, and no consistency between function calls is required. Might be wrong though.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I guess you should be more specific about *how* you'd turn 2D coordinates into vectors for which you can compute cross products.

Comment: @MvG The given points lie on the same plane, so you can take z=0 for them. But it's irrelevant, since it does not contribute to the other z's.

Comment: @MvG - I think Alexey was perfectly clear - if you actually understand vectors. v12 = (x2 - x1)i + (y2 -y1)j.  As for the ordering, I meant the comment more for the OP than Alexey.

Comment: What should the program do when one of the z equals 0 ?

Comment: How's that possible if the 4 points are the 4 vertices of a rectangle, unless it's a zero-sized rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of a zombie question, but I couldnt find a relevant newer one. So I'll post this in case it helps someone.

Here's an algorithm I've used. It relies on the following assumptions:

- its a square / rectangle: 4 vertices, edges at 90 degrees to each other
- vertices are already in sequence (either clockwise or anti-clockwise)
- its rotated by R such that -45 < R < +45 degrees

Note: it uses [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and the [scikit-image](/questions/tagged/scikit-image) coordinate convention: (Y,X) with (0,0) in the top left corner.

```py
import numpy as np
def sorted_rect(vec):
    # returns vec in clockwise order, starting with topleft
    normd = vec - np.average(vec,axis=0) # vertices relative to centroid
    tl_idx = np.argmax(np.dot(normd,np.array([-1,-1]))) #index of top left vertex
    clockwise = np.cross(vec[(tl_idx+1) % 4] - vec[tl_idx],
                         vec[tl_idx] - vec[tl_idx-1]) > 0
    return np.roll(vec,-tl_idx,axis=0) if clockwise else np.roll(vec,-1-tl_idx,axis=0)[::-1]
```